# How to define Constants in settings.py and access them in views function in django

Tags: python, django

I want to know how can i define some constants in django and use them in view.py function.
I have some variables which are never going to be changed and are used  in a function many a time. So i decided to define them as constants.

If any one can help me with the declaration of constants and how to import and use them in a function in views.py

EDIT:

constant.py

```
total_range='A1:C15'
```

view.py

```
from constant import *
def myFunction():
    ***Code to access google spreadsheet**
    cell_value_list=worksheet.range(total_range)
```

here it gives me an error saying total_range is not defined.

Comment: In your code sample `total_range` is indeed undefined, you don't show us what it is and how `MY_CUSTOM_SETTING` is used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define a variable like this i `settings.py`:

```
MY_VAR = "MY_VALUE"
```

Import settings in `views.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

You can use your variable in `views.py` like this:

```
settings.MY_VAR
```

You can make a seprate file beside views.py and define all constants on it.

for example create `constants.py` like this:

```
const1 = 'value1'
const2 = 'value2'
.
.
.
```

Now you can use constants in views.py like this:

```
from constants import *

print const1
```

Comment: I have at around 15 variables,once i import all of them, every time i use one of the constants Do i need to access them as settings.MY_VAR????

Comment: @FullOfQuestions this error not related to constant definition.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or PyCharm isn't used in giving me suggested constants from settings.py (?) I wrote settings. and I was expecting it to let me choose one of the constants, I added it hardcoded. However, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add any custom settings that you wish in your project's settings file:

```
MY_CUSTOM_SETTING = ...
```

Your custom setting can also be a dictionary if you wish not to have too many new settings.

Then you can access this setting as:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.MY_CUSTOM_SETTING ...
```

Comment: can you please help me with an example because i tried this exactly and it is giving me error that the variable is not defined. I must be doin something wrong. please help me with an example

Comment: @FullOfQuestions I have already included an example, I would recommend you to edit your question and to include any additional information such as what exactly you have tried and ehat is the error that you get.